# Java + BigQuerie how to get proper JSON instead of some list of FieldValues?

Tags: java, json, google-bigquery

I'm new to BigQuery, trying to get some values from test table. There are three columns: ID, DateTime and String. Populated some rows with current time in ms as ID, current time as UTC and current time in ms as String, so the row looks like:

1480419755489 | 2016-11-29 11:42:35 UTC | Source 14804197554881

Json in BigQuery console looks like this:

{
  "ID": "1480419755489",
  "DateTime": "2016-11-29 11:42:35 UTC",
  "String": "Source 14804197554881"
}

Everything seems OK. But in Java when I try to get this row I'm getting something bad, looking like:

[FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=1480419755489}, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=1.480419755E9}, FieldValue{attribute=PRIMITIVE, value=Source 14804197554881}]

Notice that there is no Column name in output, only some attribute; and DateTime is shown as milliseconds in form of X.YYEZ. Can this be fixed somehow or this is how it is intended to be shown? Do I need to parse every value in the response and for every row I get I must create new Json object and write values to it? Or may be I should have created a class like MyRow with correct types of data and the results of query will somehow write correct values to the objects of my class?

Answer (score 0):

Will answer my own question. These FieldValues are maps. So I used something like this:
Created my class MyRow with desired data types.
Parsed every row I got from BigQuery like that:

```
MyRow myRow = new MyRow();
myRow.setID(Integer.parseInt(row.get(0).stringValue()));
myRow.setDateTime(new Date(new BigDecimal(row.get(1).stringValue()).longValue()));
myRow.setString(row.get(2).stringValue());
```

and to see what I got:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(myRow));
```